# Why does box.set_right not work correctly?

Tags: plot, bar-chart, pine-script, pine-script-v5

The goal is to draw a box that starts with a specific bar and ends as soon as another specific bar appears. If so, a new box should start - the old one should still stay on the chart.

Conditions for to identify the start and end bar are:

```
conditionlong = close > open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi > GrenzeLong
conditionshort = close < open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi < GrenzeShort
```

Code for my box:

```
// Variables for megabar zones
var float megabarhigh = na
var float megabarlow = na
var bool inSession = na

// Box parameters
var box sessionBox = na
var color BoxColor = color.new(color.red, 85)
var color BorderColor = color.red
var bool boxright = na

// Update megabar zones
if ((close > open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi > GrenzeLong) or (close < open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi < GrenzeShort)) and na(inSession)
    megabarlow := low
    megabarhigh := high

// Check for session start
if na(inSession) and (close > open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi > GrenzeLong) or na(inSession) and (close < open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi < GrenzeShort)
    // Create a new box
    sessionBox := box.new(left=bar_index, top=megabarhigh, right=na, bottom=megabarlow, border_width=2, bgcolor=BoxColor, border_color=BorderColor)

    // Set inSession to true
    inSession := true
    

// Check for session end or continuation
if inSession
    // If conditions are not met, set inSession to false
    if not (close > open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi > GrenzeLong) or not (close < open and volume > volma * volmult and Range > rangema * rangemult and rsi < GrenzeShort)
        inSession := na
    else
        // Update right side of the box to the current bar_index + 1
        box.set_right(sessionBox, bar_index + 1)
```

The Problem:
The box does not stop. It looks like infinity boxes. Here's the result:
[image]

How can I change the code so that the box ends automatically as soon as a new one gets drawn?